# Download Switch-Firmware checksume from hp via curl

Tags: hp, firmware, checksum, md5

i backup Switchconfigurations and the Firmware via expect-script to a linuxhost. After download i want check the md5 to be sure that the transfer & firmware itself had no changes.

Is there a way to get the md5-checksum per curl from hp ?

The Script loops over a list with IP + hp-Partnumber and i can add the Version F.e.

THX
Bennoto

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to run an MD5 hash on the config or the firmware on an HPE (Aruba, Procurve, Comware) switch. You can use `show running-config hash` to display a 160-bit hash value, but HPE don't say what algorithm that uses.

Just hash the file after downloading and compare to previous hash.

Also, there's no need to backup firmware as it's the one you previously installed on the switch in question.

NB: curl is not a common way to access config or firmware files, unless you're using the REST API. It's more common to use SFTP or TFTP (unsecure).